# jQuery dynamic display of feedback query to user based on answer

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have JSON data which has some questions which I am displaying on screen using jQuery.based on users answer and need to display next question to user.
Please guide me. below I have given code sample

```
var json = '[
    {"QuestionId": 1,Question":"Question Number 1","Answer":"Answer1"},
    {"QuestionId": 2,"Question":"Question Number 2","Answer":"Answer2"},
    {"QuestionId": 3,"Question":"Question Number 3","Answer":"Answer3"},
    {"QuestionId": 4,"Question":"Question Number 4","Answer":"Answer4"},
    {"QuestionId": 5,"Question":"Question Number 5","Answer":"Answer5"}
]';
var jsonArray = $.parseJSON(json); 
$.each(jsonArray, function(index,jsonObject){
    $.each(jsonObject, function(key,val){
        console.log("key : "+key+" ; value : "+val);
        DisplayQuestionOnUI();
        //Based on Answer of first question display next question 
        //e.g. for question 1 if answer is yes then display question 4 and 5
        //otherwise display question 2 then 3
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have the key "Question" two times. Because of this the second value overwrites the first. Fix that by calling the first "QuestionId" or calling the sub-object after the id.
example:

```
var json = '[
    1:{"Question":"Question Number 1","Answer":"Answer1","NextQuestion":3},
    2:{"Question":"Question Number 2","Answer":"Answer2","NextQuestion":5},
    3:{"Question":"Question Number 3","Answer":"Answer3","NextQuestion":7},
  ]';
```

Also it is only logical to use a json syntax, if you get the data from a ajax request or similar. Otherwise you should use the normal Object initialization.

At the moment you are running through all key val pairs. Add a new Field "NextQuestion", which contains the next question id, if the answer is correct. Then you want a logic like this:

1. Ask question (display it)
2. Check the answer (in event listener of "ok" button)
3. if it is correct start again with the question with the id in "NextQuestion" and if it is wrong start again with the next question

this can be realized by recursion or a loop.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion , I have updated question to questionID. I would like to know in JSON iterator "$.each(jsonArray" how I can wait till user select answer for question . so that I can display next question.I know logically how to display next question main thing I want is just how to wait in iterator till user select answer for that question.

Comment: You should never wait in Javascript, as it freezes the whole browser! Instead you can add an onclick listener to the submit button of the answer field and check if it is correct there. Then follow the structure described in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.if question has answer yes then need to display next question 3 and 4 or if answer is no then display question 2 .Where do I store next question ID as next question varies based on answer?

Comment: I added a field called "NextQuestion" to the example in the answer. You can use it to call the next function like `askQuestion(jsonArray[currentQuestionId]["NextQuestion"]);`. Please accept the answer if it helped.          If you do not want the next question for a wrong answer you could add an other field like "NextQuestionOnWrong".

Comment: As I mentioned based on answer I need to show different question.So what you mentioned didn't work.

Comment: If you have multiple possible answers add a new object to every question with a  structure like this: `answers = {"answer1forQuestion1":3,answer2forQuestion1":5,};` If this is not what you want I think I don't undestand what you problem is.